# read process and concatenate pandas dataframe in parallel with dask

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, dask

I'm trying to read and process *in parallel* a list of csv files and concatenate the output in a single `pandas dataframe` for further processing.

My workflow consist of 3 steps:

- create a series of pandas dataframe by reading a list of csv files (all with the same structure)

  `def loadcsv(filename):
       df = pd.read_csv(filename)
       return df`
- for each dataframe create a new column by processing 2 existing columns

  `def makegeom(a,b):
       return 'Point(%s %s)' % (a,b)`

  `def applygeom(df):
       df['Geom']= df.apply(lambda row: makegeom(row['Easting'], 
                                                 row['Northing']),
                            axis=1)
       return df`
- concatenate all the dataframes in a single dataframe

  `frames = []
   for i in csvtest:
       df = applygeom(loadcsv(i))
       frames.append(df)
   mergedresult1 = pd.concat(frames)`

In my workflow I use pandas (each csv (15) file has more than >> 2*10^6 data points) so it takes a while to complete. I think this kind of workflow should take advantage of some parallel processing (at least for the `read_csv` and `apply` steps) so I gave a try to dask, but I was not able to use it properly. In my attempt I did'n gain any improvement in speed.

I made a simple notebook so to replicate what I'm doing:

https://gist.github.com/epifanio/72a48ca970a4291b293851ad29eadb50

My question is ... what's the *proper* way to use dask to accomplish my use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Pandas

In Pandas I would use the apply method

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [3, 2, 1]})

In [3]: def makegeom(row):
   ...:      a, b = row
   ...:      return 'Point(%s %s)' % (a, b)
   ...: 

In [4]: df.apply(makegeom, axis=1)
Out[4]: 
0    Point(1 3)
1    Point(2 2)
2    Point(3 1)
dtype: object
```

#### Dask.dataframe

In dask.dataframe you can do the same thing

```
In [5]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [6]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

In [7]: ddf.apply(makegeom, axis=1).compute()
Out[7]: 
0    Point(1 3)
1    Point(2 2)
2    Point(3 1)
```

#### Add new series

In either case you can then add the new series to the dataframe

```
df['geom'] = df[['a', 'b']].apply(makegeom)
```

#### Create

If you have CSV data then I would use the dask.dataframe.read_csv function

```
ddf = dd.read_csv('filenames.*.csv')
```

If you have other kinds of data then I would use [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html)

Comment: I’m now trying to use delayed: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/34816085f0dfc2e26a5130a59aa920c1
but it is still working … 'htop' show that all the cpu are working but not at 100% I see 8 processes working at ~15% I'll try your approach. My data are stored as feather binary files (In the example I used csv to simplify a little my use case)

Comment: Your makegeom function is bound by the GIL.  You should read http://dask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html to learn about choosing a good scheduler for your situation.

Comment: I’m still working on my issue. I changed the ```makegeom``` function, replacing ```apply``` with custom ```numpy``` code (which is much faster). Now I'm working on a [new notebook](https://gist.github.com/epifanio/b675c596c3b717ff08bbfef4a36879b2). My plan is to first learn a bit about queues and 'shared objects' among processes  then understand how to use dask with distribute.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I have found other ways (alternative to Dask), in my opinion relatively easier, to perform a function `func` in parallel over a pandas data frame. In both cases, I took advantage of the [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) method.

One uses a combination of the python `multiprocessing.Pool`, [`numpy.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and will work this way:

```py
import numpy as np

def func(array):
    # do some computation on the given array
    pass

def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=72):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores)
    pool = Pool(n_cores)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return df
```

Another is by using the powerful but simple [`ray`](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/cluster/) cluster (which is quite useful if you can run the code over multiple machines):

```
# connect to a ray cluster
# 

import ray

ray.init(address="auto", redis_password="5241590000000000")

import numpy as np


@ray.remote
def func(df):
    # do some computation on the given dataframe
    pass

df_split = np.array_split(df, 288)
result = pd.concat(ray.get([func.remote(i) for i in df_split]))
```

The methods above are working quite well for simple methods `func` where the computation can be carried out with numpy and the product which is returned can be concatenated back into a pandas data frame - for methods that do simpler file manipulation I also found useful `parmap.map`  - but that is off-topic for this S.O. question.